# ng-select AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to put together an ng select to select these quantities:

```
   "splits":[  
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      8
   ],


<select  ng-options="?" ng-model="ticket_group.quantity" </select>
```

Then I want to show the price multiplied by the quantity they have chose

```
 <div style="text-align: center;font-size:25px;"><b> ${{ticket_group.retail_price * ticket_quantity}} USD</b>
```

So would I just reference the ng-model for this?

Please help me figure out ng-select and have it display the final price

Comment: If this question isn't clear, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-model` is not the problem, considering you expect `$scope.ticker_group.quantity` to hold the value at the end.

What you need to set is `ng-options`. First of all, those options must be in the scope:

```
$scope.splits = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    8
];
```

This is an example. You used a key (i.e. `splits` belonged to a literal object) so you must ensure the object having such key belongs (directly or not) to the `$scope`.

Following MY example, `splits` is now in the scope, so I can use it as data-binding expression in the `ng-options`.

`ng-options` expects key:value are specified, so the syntax is:

```
ng-options="foo as bar for (foo, bar) in anObject"
```

So if you have any object, you can iterate keys (properties) and values. notice that `foo` and `bar` are examples (you can use any name, being sure such names are not reserved words), where `foo` is declared in the place to define the keys (i.e. the `value` attribute of each `option` object), and `bar` is declared in the place to define labels for such options.

As an alternative, if you iterate an array object instead of other classes object, you can specify like this:

```
ng-options="foo as foo for foo in anArray"
```

which will generate options having the value as the label (same contents). You will use them like this:

```
ng-options="val as val for val in splits"
```

AND if you have a case where you have an array of objects and want to specify value and label from properties of such objects, like:

```
$scope.people = [{dni:32111269, nombre:"Pepe Galleta"}, {dni:11111111, nombre:"Nestor Kirchner"}, {dni:12345678, name:"Mi Abuela"}, {dni: 23456789, nombre:"Tu Hermana"}];
```

And want to make `dni` as the value, and `nombre` as the label, You'd use:

```
ng-options="foo.dni as foo.nombre for foo in people"
```

See more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

**Who will hold the value?**: The expression you set in the `ng-model` directive will be the holder of the selected value once you use the selector.

You want, perhaps, to use a:

```
$scope.$watch('splits', function(v){
    ...
});
```

to show the price being modified by the value on `splits`.

Comment: Thanks so much!! so you would recommend using this line? ng-options="foo as bar for (foo, bar) in anObject" - if so can you write out an example using my object names?

Comment: For this line; ng-options="val as val for val in splits"  what would I use as "val"?

Comment: I realized that val as val for val in ticket_group.splits is the perfect solution... but question whats the difference between an array object and a class object?

Comment: These's no actual difference. Except that, in an array, you know the order of the elements. But you can use as you want: an object, or an array with elements having a field (or method) which will be used as key, and a field (or method) which will be used as label. this is about models, and it just up to you.